# Still not able to access file in external storage even after requesting permission in app (Marshmallow), need to relaunch app to gain access?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am testing in emulator using Marshmallow. Here's what I did: when first launching the app, I checked if the Camera / Storage permission is on or not. If it's NOT, I will request the permission for these: `Manifest.permission.CAMERA`, `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. In later screen, I launched a picker that provides option for taking phone from camera or loading from gallery. During the process, the image is saved in external storage.

Here's what I did:

I granted both permission for Camera and Storage when the system dialog prompt. Then, I select to load from gallery. During the process, at some point, I call this method to get the image:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
```

where `imagePath` is the path in the external storage. And in Marshmallow, the above line generate this error:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/storage/1E03-0606/IMG_1452715979191.jpg**: open failed: EACCES (**Permission denied**)

From above error message, it seems that the permission to access the storage is still denied even after I granted the permission for Storage (I double checked in **Setting** after clicking "Allow" in the system dialog, both Camera and Storage becomes turned on.)

I did further check for the `imagePath` to make sure it exists and is a file:

```
File f = new File(imagePath);
if(f.exists() && f.isFile()){
     System.out.println("file \"" +  imagePath + "\" exists & is a file." );
}
```

So this means that I did have the file generated in storage, but still the permission is denied even I granted it already from the system dialog.

The observation: I killed the app and launched it again. Now the Camera & Storage permissions are on since I granted it from the system dialog previously, and this time, the above code works:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
```

So it looks like when requesting a permission programmatically in the app, it does appear right away if checking in **Setting**, but the actual grant won't take effect until you shut down the app and relaunch it again?!

I read somewhere, if the permission is revoked manually through **Setting** when your app is running, the app will terminate itself.

Comment: Did you resolved the problem? I have this too.

Answer (score 0):

> but the actual grant won't take effect until you shut down the app and relaunch it again??!!

No this is incorrect - you immediately get permission/access.

Just to clarify, just because you now have access to the file-system, does not mean you have access to all files - you still have to work within the system of file permissions (so that apps cannot access each other's databases for example).

It's impossible to know what the exact issue is without more information, but make sure you do your `f.exists() && f.isFile()` check immediately after you've written and *closed* the file handler - it's very possible the file simply did not exist when you tried to read it as per the `FileNotFoundException` exception.

Comment: I tried that with the following code:File f = new File(imagePath);
if(f.exists() && f.isFile()){
     System.out.println("file \"" +  imagePath + "\" exists & is a file." );
} and it does print out the message, so the file exists in the storage.

Comment: what's the return value of `f.canRead()` ?

Comment: ,Also I tried to open & read the file and got the same error message: **E/File open & Read test﹕ Unable to open file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1E03-0606/IMG_1452724368920.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

Comment: What was the return value?

Comment: f.canRead() => false

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do a media scan to get the system to recognize your file.  I had the same issue with downloading a file and this code worked for me:

```
File file = new File(imagePath);

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    boolean weAreOK = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(files[i].getName(), fos);

    fos.flush();
    fos.getFD().sync();
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
         new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
         new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                  Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                  Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                                                    }
         });
    fos.close();


} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("File Exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: not sure if I am having the same issue as you had. Do you do this scan in an activity? I.e., "this" is an instance of activity in your code? Thanks.

Comment: In my case the "this" is a service, but it can be the context of an activity.  (I've also done it in that case).  It was weird.  You could see the file on the device, but the system could not find it right away.  Eventually, though the file showed up on its own, but that wasn't good enough for my app.

Comment: I just called like this in my activity: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(act,
                    new String[]{absolutePath}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                           AnotherMethod(String imagePath, Activity act);
                        }
                    }); And in the AnotherMethod(), it eventually calls BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options); Then, the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing in emulator with Marshmallow, and this morning I updated the phone to Android 6.0.1 and tested in this phone, the issue I was experiencing in the emulator as asked in the question is not there any more!